# Codeigniter - Forgot Password

Tags: codeigniter, passwords

Hello: I need to implement a forgot password to a login page. Here I explained what I have so far.

1. Recover view is prompt to received email input
2. Function `email_exists()` will verify email. If so, `send_email()` with `$temp_pass` key and link.The database will store $temp_pass for further action and verification.
3. User clicks on the link previously sent passing `$temp_pass` to function reset_password.
4. The model controller will verify `$temp_pass` with database. If so, load view to input new password - and here is where I am stuck because the form points to a controller that does not recognizes `$temp_pass` therefore unable to reset password.

How can I retrieved the new password, associated with the right user and reset password?

Code below:

### Controller

```
    public function recover(){
    //Loads the view for the recover password process.
    $this->load->view('recover');
}
public function recover_password(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');

            //check if email is in the database
        $this->load->model('model_users');
        if($this->model_users->email_exists()){
            //$them_pass is the varible to be sent to the user's email 
            $temp_pass = md5(uniqid());
            //send email with #temp_pass as a link
            $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype'=>'html'));
            $this->email->from('user@yahoo.com', "Site");
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
            $this->email->subject("Reset your Password");

            $message = "<p>This email has been sent as a request to reset our password</p>";
            $message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."main/reset_password/$temp_pass'>Click here </a>if you want to reset your password,
                        if not, then ignore</p>";
            $this->email->message($message);

            if($this->email->send()){
                $this->load->model('model_users');
                if($this->model_users->temp_reset_password($temp_pass)){
                    echo "check your email for instructions, thank you";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "email was not sent, please contact your administrator";
            }

        }else{
            echo "your email is not in our database";
        }
}
public function reset_password($temp_pass){
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    if($this->model_users->is_temp_pass_valid($temp_pass)){

        $this->load->view('reset_password');

    }else{
        echo "the key is not valid";    
    }

}
public function update_password(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]');
            if($this->form_validation->run()){
            echo "passwords match"; 
            }else{
            echo "passwords do not match";  
            }
}
```

### Model_users

```
    public function email_exists(){
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email='$email'");    
    if($row = $query->row()){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
 }
public function temp_reset_password($temp_pass){
    $data =array(
                'email' =>$this->input->post('email'),
                'reset_pass'=>$temp_pass);
                $email = $data['email'];

    if($data){
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->update('users', $data);  
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }

}
public function is_temp_pass_valid($temp_pass){
    $this->db->where('reset_pass', $temp_pass);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: See how ion auth does it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure where you are stuck at. I can get the fact that you are creating a temporary flag for a user which you verify when the user clicks the link. So, that means, you can start with a session at that point, and the user can only reset the password, only if that particular session is active.

After this step, you ask the user to input his new password, and since you have the temporary flag which you call as `$temp_pass` for the user (please take care that it should be unique), then you can get the user who is trying to reset the password.

So, all you need to do is to run a db query of this kind -

```
$this->db->where('reset_pass', $temp_pass);
$this->db->update('users', $data); // where $data will have the fields with values you are updating
```

---

### I guess you made an error

Also, I just noticed in your `recover_password()` function -

```
$message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."main/reset_password/$temp_pass'>Click here </a>if you want to reset your password, if not, then ignore</p>";
```

Shouldn't the above line be -

```
$message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."main/reset_password/".$temp_pass."'>Click here </a>if you want to reset your password, if not, then ignore</p>";
```

### Update

You can pass `$temp_pass` into the sessions and retrieve from there. That's one way to go about it.

Comment: You are right the syntax for $message has an error/bug. The funny thing is that I am still able to retrieve it ($temp_pass) and pass it to my model_users (is_temp_valid_key) for verification. Anyways, I am making the changes.

Comment: I do not know where to put the piece of code you just gave me. The function reset_password($temp_pass) is the one that kicks on as soon as the user clicks on the link and therefore it evaluates if the $temp_pass is valid or not and it returns true so that it loads the view to retrieve the new password. Now the form points to update_password() but is not able to pass $temp_pass anymore to update db: $this->db->update('users', $data); because it does not know which user?? Im stuck right there... Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Actually PHP does variable substitution within double quoted strings so the first version actually is supposed to work thought it is considered good practice to use the variation with curly braces: `"main/reset_password/{$temp_pass}'>Clic...`

Comment: @user1728037 you can pass `$temp_pass` into the sessions and retrieve from there. That's one way to go about it.

Comment: @Aniket I am lost, where do I need to start a session? I think it should go before the view is load right? But then my function update_password in my model users does not update password. Any help? I will appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest some improvements to your password-reset procedure.

1. If you store the reset information separate from the user-model in an own database table, you could store other informations like an expiry date, the user id, and an already-used-flag together with the token. The user model would stay clean, several resets would not interfere with each other.
2. The reset tokens should not be stored directly in the database, instead you should store only a **hash** of the tokens. An attacker with read access to the database (SQL-injection) could otherwise reset any account he wishes.
3. The token should be unpredictable, `md5(uniqid())` can be narrowed down badly if you know the time the reset was done.

I published some [example code](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset), how such a password-reset procedure could look like, together with a class which can generate safe tokens.

Comment: I read your article. This question is not about your answer, but about your website. Why most programmers (including you) personal sites are ugly looking. I mean you can easily buy WordPress theme and write the blog. Or even custom design it not takes too much time... What is the reason most programmers sites are ugly.........

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson - Better now? I just released a new tool [SilentNotes](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/silentnotes/) and redesigned the site to make it responsive for small phones.